# MSCAL.OCX not working on MS Access 2010(64-bit) on Windows 10(64-bit)

Tags: ms-access, calendar, vba, ms-access-2010

We have a legacy system developed in Access. It has some Microsoft Calendar Control(mscal.calendar.7 to be specific). Now we are trying to run in MS Access 2010(64-bit on Windows 10) but it gives error on the calendar control line which is 
`CurrentDate.Value` where CurrentDate is the calendar control name,
the error we are getting is
`Runtime error 2683`

`There is no object in the control`

We have tried by copying(and registering using `regsrv32`) the `mscal.ocx` file, but still we are getting the same error.
Also, there is no missing library reference when see in `Tools->References...`

This application is developed using the 12.0 version of `mscal.ocx` plugin.

Comment: Dll (and ocx is a dll) can only be loaded in the same bitness. Exe are different.

Comment: But, i am able to register using regsvr32 successfully.
Anything else you would like to suggest??

Comment: Then use 32 bit office.

Comment: tried that too, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 64-bit OS, you need to register mscal.ocx with 32-bit regsvr32 located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe mscal.ocx
```

That, in combination with office 32-bit should work.

Comment: It did worked after a clean installation of 32-bit office